# Won't an app based on immutable data structures run out of memory?

Tags: out-of-memory, immutability, immutable.js, ramda.js

Never mind redux or something - I am solely asking about Immutable.JS, Ramda, etc.

If new versions of a data structure is created by structural sharing, that means that every new version needs to have a pointer to the previous version in order for it to be able to share anything. That again means that older versions of a structure cannot be garbage collected, meaning again, that in an app where you have state, this state will use a monotonically increasing amount of memory. If this is the case, then that data structure will at some point have used all available memory, if it keeps getting modified.

Am I missing something here? I can see that for many (most) use cases on the web (in a browser), this won't be a problem, as you are probably just changing a tiny part of the structure each time, and you will probably leave the page or reload it way before you use all memory, but for long running processes this should pose a problem. Right? Riiight?

Comment: I feel that question (and my answer) should better go to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If new versions of a data structure is created by structural sharing, that means that every new version needs to have a pointer to the previous version in order for it to be able to share anything.

This is not correct in general. The new version would have pointers to *subparts* of the previous version. So it shares a *fraction* (
often *almost* all) of the data of the older version.

For example, Ocaml's maps ([represented](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/map.mli) and [implemented](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/blob/trunk/stdlib/map.ml) by some [self-balancing binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) variant of [red-black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)) are immutable: see documentation of [Map](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.html). But if you add (or remove) some binding to (from) a map, you get a *new* map sharing *most* (but not all) of its internal nodes with the old one.

So the garbage collector would eventually "delete" those *old* internal nodes which are not relevant to the current "state".

BTW web programming (and web navigation) is related to [continuations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) and [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). See e.g. Byrd's [*Web Programming with Continuations*](https://thelackthereof.org/docs/library/cs/continuations.pdf) and several papers by [C.Queinnec](https://pages.lip6.fr/Christian.Queinnec/WWW/Queinnec.html).

Read also more about [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)) in functional programming.